# python script to list all of the files and directories that have been created

Tags: python

spython script to list all of the files and directories that have been created

Comment: "Note that the current directory is usually referred to as /" This is your homework. Do your own work.

Comment: On what system is the current directory usually referred to as `/`?

Comment: @user1675137 I think `.` represents the current directory in unix.

Comment: i tryed to determine the time now 

time=dt.datetime.now()

and the time that given my user  
ago=now-dt.timedelta(minutes=userinput)

Comment: And `/` refers to the root directory on Unix. That's why `sudo rm -rf /` is funnier than `sudo rm -rf .`.

Comment: You tried it… and what happened? Who told you to type `dt.datetime.now()` instead of `datetime.datetime.now()`? And if someone told you to use the `time` module, why are you using the `datetime` module instead?

Comment: i tryed to determine the time now 

time=dt.datetime.now()

and the time that given my user  
ago=now-dt.timedelta(minutes=userinput)

and i think  i would use os.path.join  and os.stat  

but my probleme is how to return list  of files in subdirectories  .

Comment: becouse import datetime as dt 
its the same   we imported the datetime as dt !  its like shoutcut

Comment: You can return the list of files in any directory with `os.listdir(dirpath)`. You can check whether any of those files is a subdirectory with `os.path.isdir(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))`, and then recursively traverse that directory. Writing that would be a very useful learning experience. Alternatively, you could skim the `os` documentation, or just look at my answer, and see that `os.walk` already does that for you.

Comment: Thank you  abarnert That was helpful , also i will take a look on os documentation  and do you think we will need 1 loop or two ?

Comment: Using `walk`, you always need two or three loops—it iterates over directories, and gives you a list of directories and a list of files for each one. See the `rmdir` example in the `os.walk` docs for how to loop over everything.

Comment: Ok  abarnert i will see the example . thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without giving you the entire answer, here are the parts you need:

- [walk](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk): `os.walk('.')` iterates over all of the files and directories in `.` and any of its subdirectories. You can wrap a `for` loop around that. Look at the examples to get the `os.path.join(dirpath, filename)` and other details right.
- [stat](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat): `os.stat(pathname)` returns a `stat` object with information about the file at `pathname`. Depending on your platform, either `st_ctime` or `st_birthtime` may be the creation time. (On some platforms, there is no way to get it.) The format is seconds since the epoch.
- The [time](http://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) module: You've already been told about this. Get the current time at startup, using your favorite seconds-since-the-epoch function. Any file where `starttime - create time <= X * 60` is new. (But make sure you get the timezone stuff right—use either GMT or local time for both file times and current times.)